# Binomial coefficient modulo

Tags: binomial-coefficients

It is well known that $ \gcd(n,r) = 1 \implies \binom{n}{r} \equiv 0 \mod n $

Then my doubt is that is there any general formula if $\gcd(n,r) \ne 1$

I.e.,

$$r \ne 0 \land r \ne  n \land \gcd(n,r) \ne 1 \implies \binom{n}{r} \equiv ? \mod n$$

If $r=0,n$, then obviously $?= 1$.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222637/binomial-coefficient-modulo-prime-power?rq=1) link and [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) can help.

Comment: @ccorn taken, edited.

Comment: Recommended reading: Andrew D. Loveless: *A Congruence for Products of Binomial Coefﬁcients modulo a Composite*, in: [INTEGERS 7](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/vol7.html) (A44, 10 Jan 2007).